# When did they start making SMD2835 and others

Tags: led, surface-mount, manufacturing

i'm trying to build the chart of LED efficacy and power change over the past couple of years.

does anybody know when did they start making 2835, 3528, 3014, 5630? google gives me 2015ish for 2835, but I do remember using them way before 2015.

Comment: Why look at dimensions of the package, if you want power and luminosity?  "2835" means 2.8mm x 3.2mm (about 0.110 x 0.126 inches) in size.

Comment: would be nice to have chronological change of package, power and output. I'm pretty sure they would make real small package with unlimited luminosity if they knew how to combine it in tiny chips

Comment: Don't you think it would be difficult enough just to list the efficacy of current LEDs?  Like which LED currently has a wall plug efficiency better than 80%?